# NUnit TestCase tests seem to be ignored by NCover

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, ncover

NCover seems to refuse to report coverage from NUnit parameterized tests.

This goes fine:

```
    [Test]
    public void CreateImportTvShowsModelTests()
    {
        var importTvShowsModel = new ImportTvShowsModel(_fileUtilities, null, _tvShowLibrary, new ProgressModel());

        Assert.IsNotNull(importTvShowsModel.TvShowLibrary);
    }
```

This is ignored in the coverage report:

```
    [TestCase(false, true, true)]
    [TestCase(false, false, true)]
    [TestCase(true, true, false)]
    [TestCase(false, false, true)]
    public void ToggleSelectAll(bool firstSelected, bool secondSelected, bool resultAllSelected)
    {
        // Go into some trouble to use actual DownloadedEpisodes (not mocks) because we need to validate
        // the IsSelected propery. Mocking the IsSelected property on DownloadedEpisode superseeds the whole purpose
        var matcher = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISeasonAndEpisodeMatcher>();
        var tvShowsLibrary = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITvShowsLibrary>();
        tvShowsLibrary.Expect(library => library.PossibleCorrespondingTvShows(string.Empty))
                      .IgnoreArguments()
                      .Return(new List<ITvShow>());

        var downloadedEpisode1 = new DownloadedEpisode(@"D:\bla.mkv", matcher, tvShowsLibrary) {IsSelected = firstSelected};
        var downloadedEpisode2 = new DownloadedEpisode(@"D:\bla.mkv", matcher, tvShowsLibrary) {IsSelected = secondSelected};

        var downloadedEpisodes = new ObservableCollection<IDownloadedEpisode> { downloadedEpisode1, downloadedEpisode2 };
        var importTvShowsModel = new ImportTvShowsModel(_fileUtilities, downloadedEpisodes, _tvShowLibrary, _progressModel);
        importTvShowsModel.ToggleSelectAll();

        Assert.AreEqual(resultAllSelected, downloadedEpisode1.IsSelected);
        Assert.AreEqual(resultAllSelected, downloadedEpisode2.IsSelected);
    }
```

Of course in both cases the tests are executed and all succeed.

Can I tweak NCover in a way that it does report the coverage for parameterized tests?

Comment: Interesting issue, which I have not come across. It seems pretty fundamental that this would work. Did you try the NCover support?

Comment: Done that, will report back if I get a solution. Thx for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated to latest version (4.5.2483.*) and now it is a supported feature. \o/